# Is it possible to redirect a react route from express?

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I'm new to mern so wondering if this is even possible or if there are other solutions(trying to validate if a user is a user exists or not which works, then redirect to the same page which doesn't work). I know about window.location in react but I don't know how to redirect if a user already exists from react - code is below:

**react register js:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Axios from "axios";

const Register = () => {
    const [regUsername, setRegUsername] = useState('')
    const [regPassword, setRegPassword] = useState('')

    const submitUser = () => {
        // testing if connected to express route
        Axios({
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                username: regUsername,
                password: regPassword,
            },
            withCredentials: true,
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/users'
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
           // window.location = "/"
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }

    return (
        <div className="Register">
            <h1>Register Page</h1><br />
                <label>username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value={regUsername} onChange={(e) => setRegUsername(e.target.value)} required></input><br></br>

                <label>passowrd</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value={regPassword} onChange={(e) => setRegPassword(e.target.value)} required></input><br />

                <button onClick={submitUser}>sign up</button>         

            <br />
            <Link to="/login" type="button"> Login here</Link>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Register
```

**users.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const userModel = require('../models/userModel')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

// GET users
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const users = await userModel.find()
    res.json(users)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({message: err})
  }
})

// POST users to db
router.post('/', (req,res) =>{


  // checking if user already exists
  userModel.findOne({username: req.body.username}, async (err, user) =>{
    // handle any errors
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    // if username already exists in db
    if(user){
      res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/')
    }
    if(!user){
      // hashing password before submitted to db
      const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)

      // new instance of user model to be mutated    
      const User = new userModel({
          // grabbing user register data and pushing to mongo
          username: req.body.username,
          password: hashedPass
      })
      const newUser = await User.save()
      res.json(newUser)  
    }
  })
})

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, a `fetch` or AJAX call from JavaScript will not follow the redirect header sent from the server. You would have to read the header manually, but [from the documentation, it seems like Axios does this for you](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config). Have you tried making the call yet?

If you don't want a full-page, you may need to do this another way with React Router, but the idea is the same, getting the URL from the response headers and supplying that to the React Router `history.replace()`.